# 3 column layout with inline block not working- the divs aren't lining up correctly

Tags: css, html

I have a div which contains three child div's, and for some reason the first child div is properly positioned within its parent, but the other two children are positioned lower from the first child. The more content I add to the first child the lower the other children become positioned relative to the top of the container parent.

Heres a jfiddle showing you my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/gY72a/7/

the three children arent on the same line here but you can see the problem when you look at how high the first child is positioned compared to the second one.

Code is already in the jfiddle, but here is the css I am using:

```
/*Parent div in which all three children are nested*/

#main {
width: 80%;
min-width: 1000px;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
margin: 1% auto;
border-radius: 1px;
border: 0px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

/*First child*/

#leftside {
display: inline-block;
width: 18%;
margin: 10px 1% 8px;
padding: 1em;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

/*Second Child*/

#innermain {
display: inline-block; 
width: 50%; 
margin: 10px 1% 8px;  
padding:1em; 
background-color: #eaeaea;
border-radius: 1px;
border: 0px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

/*Third child*/

#rightside {
width: 20%;
min-width: 320px;
padding: 1em 0px;
display: inline-block;
background: #FFFFFF;
margin: 10px 1% 8px ;
border-radius: 1px;
border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
```

Comment: Is this a small project you are just starting where you could add a global rule at this stage? * { box-sizing: border-box } ? because that would change how I would suggest you deal with this.

Comment: Unfortunately this is a site that was nearing completion but I had to add more content and so decided to redo the entire layout

Comment: So, that means that you CAN? Your life will be much much happier if you accept `box-sizing: border-box` into it.

Comment: It a big question, like "how does CSS positioning work in general" - but I tried to answer it as best I could. If you find the time, I would encourage you to revisit the very basics of static, relative, absolute, etc - positioning - and how they work in various situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem here is that you are using `display:inline-block" and also that you are using a combination of percentages and margins with ems. Now, theoretically, you could have 3 blocks, and add their widths and the padding, and the margin - to all equal 100, but even if you wanted to go that route, you are using the inline-block method - which by default leaves a little unwanted space between each block, and throws off that number. Beyond that, padding and margins add to the size of the box, so if you have a box that is 20% wide, and has a padding of 1em and a margin of 1% - then it's 20%+2%+2em (+total border width) - and what does that equal? Well, I don't know - and the browser isn't going to love dealing with that either, because depending on window size, that number is going to be different. So, if you want to know the problem, those are the factors leading to the problems.

If you want a solution, then you have a few routes, but they depend on what you need to do. It doesn't appear as though you are building this site responsively. So in that case, you are working with a 1000px wide canvas. - and in that case, then there is no reason why you cant just use px to add up margin/padding/box size etc to equal 100. leave the boxes as `display: block;` and float them left.

If you want to come into the present, and start using a bit of modern stuff - you should read about `box-sizing: border-box` - What that does is change the box model so that the padding and borders of boxes moves inside the box and therefore doesn't add to it's size. It's really great and makes working with css a pleasure. Then you don't have to add stuff up to determine the box's size. - so - unless you need to support IE 7 - I would suggest you make it standard in your overall approach to CSS from now on. http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

If you are going to float the columns in their "wrapper" thing - then that wrapper thing is no longer going to regognize them in the same way, so you are going to have to look up clearfixing the div, or use overflow:hidden; (which has some issues) or float that wrapper itself to get them to live in the same world again, because floating takes the elements out of the regular flow.

In the case that you can go with box-sizing, then you still have to worry about margins(they don't move inside the box). So, you'll need to have those in percentages, or get another fancy way of making consistent gutter widths, but since you have a static sized site - I'm not going to go into that.

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/YF5AB/) without all of your styles - to show how it works.

### HTML

```
<div class="content-wrapper">

    <div class="column what">
        <h2>What We do</h2>
        <p>Bla bla bla</p>
    </div>

    <div class="column main-content">
        <h2>Latest News and Events</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="column where">
         <h2>Where To Find Us</h2>   
    </div>

</div> <!-- .content-wrapper -->
```

### CSS

```
*, *:before, *:after {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.content-wrapper {
    width: 1000px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow: hidden; /* should be clearfix instead */
}

.column { /* what the columns have in common */
    float: left;
    padding: 1em;
}

.what {
    width: 25%;
    margin-right: 1%;
    background-color: orange;
}

.main-content {
    width: 48%;
    margin-right: 1%;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.where {
    width: 25%;
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: I'm glad. I didn't want to confuse things, but note the `.column` situation, the more shared styles you can get going as reusable modules, the more global control you will have. And I suggest leaving out the `id`'s unless for javascript, as they will complicate things in hierarchy later.

Comment: I applied box-sizing and its working out terrific, this is so much more intuitive than before. only problem is this is only supported by css3 right? so if someone is using an older browser what would be a good fall back method?

Comment: im still not sure if i want to make the site responsive or not, the thing is I tried to plan out a mobile layout and a desktop, but i really want users to get the same experience on a mobile device. a lot of our visitors might not have desktop PC's so I think that having all of the content right there is more important than it being a tad inconvenient to have to double tap to zoom in and scroll around to view all the content.

Comment: Well, I have personally never read an entire article like that. Going back and fourth across sentences is not fun. Depending on the project, you have to decide, but if you are planning on working on the web for your primary job, you might as well stay ahead of the game. There are a ton of people who know bootstrap, but hardly anyone who thinks about new design patterns and ways of getting this content readable and enjoyable on all devices. I've been folding things up a lot lately with javascript for small phones, and then revealing more as the screen allows.

Comment: Here is how I would do it. Pretty small amount of code:  http://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/lHsDF/

Comment: regarding fallback - if you are supporting IE 7, then you are a masochist and you like the pain - the real problem is media queries in IE 8. weigh lost visitors on mobile to lost visitors on IE 7 and 8 --- then if you really need 8, charge then an extra 20% of your total fee, and make an IE specific set of styles.

Comment: You should rename your question to something like, 3 column layout with inline block not working etc. No one will ever search for your title.

Comment: I'd like to eventually develop for the web full-time, right now I am in the early stages of learning, the site I am working on is actually the first website I've made. I'm doing tracks on teamtreehouse and using code-academy to teach myself as much as possible and I'm going to school in the fall full-time to begin a bachelors in computer science. Goal is to have a decent grasp on html5, css3, javascript, and a server side language like php or ruby by then. If I could earn a couple bucks making websites while in school I'd be happy with that.

Comment: Nice codepen by the way, I know zilch about js as of right now but I played with my browser window and I love what it does! That could be perfect. I'm going to try implementing that in my code, thanks. I'm doing a track on teamtreehouse right now thats still going over the basics of html and css, thing is I have been teaching myself html and css for a few months now and I just began to use teamtreehouse a week or two ago, so a lot of the stuff I am learning on there I already know. But its always good to get a fresh perspective and I manage to learn a new thing or two along the way.

Comment: Looking forward to digging into more advanced css and beginning javascript and dom manipulation and server-side programming!

Comment: i implemented the code from your codepen into my site, all of my classes are named correctly and wrapped properly and the layout and media querys work, only problem is that the javascript doesn't seem to be working. when i re-size the browser down to the specified media screen call, the content doesn't hide into the section latches, instead the section latches and close buttons display above and below each one of the columns. all of the classes have the correct names in the html, css and javascript so that isnt the problem, strange.

Comment: im having trouble figuring out what the folded-up-state does, you have it as display:none; and then with javascript your creating it and the media query is using it when the browser is 500px wide, but what is it for?

Comment: It sounds to me like you aren't grabbing jQuery and putting it in your html. Could that be the case? folded up state is just a class that hides it. This is toggled with jQuery in this case. Try looking at it in the codepen with javascript off and see what that's like, then turn it on, and see how it changes things. As far as online classes, that's great. Just building stuff is good though - find a site, copy it. make is responsive - etc. They aren't going to teach you how to solve responsive problems, because they haven't had them yet. They are unique to content.

Comment: ALSO - that css is SCSS... - you can click the "SCSS" label near it and compile it to CSS and use that if you aren't using sass.

Comment: I cut the javascript from my html and then tested the site out, your right the browser isnt running the jquery for some reason. I have the script in my head tag, and I also have a link with the src pointing to jquery, i am using jquery for the navigation in my site as well and that works without a hitch.

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` is in my head and so is the script from your codepen.

Comment: did a simple hello world test with jquery and that ran fine also

Comment: thank you immensely for taking the time to write up that code-pen, its perfect!

Answer (score 0):

You have specified `display:inline-block` for the `div`s below which should align them properly in a row with the widths given. But the `width` is taken by the content section of the `div` and the `div` adds the `margin`s given to them with the width. This is why the blocks are jumping below one another.

When you apply `box-sizing: border-box;` to the `div`s, the width of the div will be calculated including the `margin`s given to the corresponding `div`s. 
Hope this helps you.

```
#main, #leftside, #innermain{
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
```

Comment: This isn't going to teach the OP what is happening or how to fix it. A link to something that actually explains the box model, and a short description of how this might help the OP would be a great answer. If you are going to use box-sizing, then you might as well start using it on everything, in which case - you'll need to fully understand what that means globally.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
#main div {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: If you were just starting out, would this answer help you?

Comment: thanks but that doesnt help me, the child divs are already in a row the problem is that they are positioned differently height wise

Comment: Adding float without changing from inline-block to block doesn't show much conviction.